# How to handle user clicked local notification

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am using local notification in my app, the only thing i care about is what exact notification the user clicked.

the method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

triggered when the notification is received but i need to handle the notification when the user clicked on it so this is useless to me.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

triggered only when app was not running, also not what i need

i searched the net but found only handles if the app is active or not running. how can i handle it when the app is on the background?

what i need in other words is to recognise the exact notification that the user clicked when the app was running on the background

Answer (score 5):

When creating your UILocalNotification, you can set the `userInfo` to set any associated data/unique identifiers.

Ex.

```
UILocalNotification *someNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[someNotification setUserInfo:@{ kSomeUniqueIdentifierKey : @"identifier" }];
```

and then,

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.userInfo[kSomeUniqueIdentifierKey] isEqualToString:@"identifier"]) {
        // We know what notification was responded to based on userInfo
    }
}
```

The above method fires either immediately upon receiving the notification while the app was running or when the user taps the notification that fired while your app was in the background.

If you want to ignore these notifications while the app is running, you could always check the state of the application to determine if it's responding to the notification while running or in the background.

Comment: this function only fired when the notification is sent at the first time.

Comment: deprecated in iOS 10

Answer (score -1):

I am working with iOS 9, and the solution is to check the launchOptions within the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. As follows:

```
    // Were we launched from a local notification?
    if let lo = launchOptions
    {
        if let ln = lo[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification
        {
            // Do our thing...
        }
    }
```

Comment: i asked it almost 3 years ago! your answer is not relevant.